# Cannot access an activity B outside activity A

Tags: android

I have this demo app I am working on. It contains two activities, A and B. A activity has an arraylist of string and a menu button. B activity has an arraylist but it only shows the items selected in A. It is working fine except that I am unable to access B directly from any other activity (ex: activity C). It gives me nullpointerexception. That is I am able to see the content of activityB only when I press the menu button and click on show activity B option. The code for this is below

```
    @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_settings:
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        myIntent.putExtra("key", finalList);
        startActivity(myIntent);

        break;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Is it cuz I have putExtra here so I can access activity B through menu option of activity A(something like only when activity B is selected from menu it will display activity B)? How can I make it so that I can access activity B from anywhere I want.

Comment: What error does it give when you try to start Activity B from C?

Comment: what do you mean by access activity B?

Comment: It gives me java.lang.runtimeException: unable to instantiate android.app.Application: java.lang.nullPointerException

Comment: By access I mean start activity B directly without going through activity A all the time

Comment: @VyprNoch get to know the activity lifecycle from the docs. ALso check the topic Task and Backstack in the docs.

Comment: Thanks I will check and see if that answers it

Comment: Are you adding the Extra each time? I could see if throwing a NPE if you expect the extra content, and don't add it.

Comment: Yes each time Activity B is started from menu->Activity B, the Extra is added as shown in above code. But if I start activity B from another activity then the Extra isnt added. So do you think that is the problem?

Comment: @Choker Thanks a ton!!! that was the problem. It was expecting the Extra but not getting it. Thanks dude....

Comment: No problem, just ran into the same situation myself recently.